# Low power way to switch on MOSFET with ~100mV input singal?

Tags: mosfet

Is there a low power (single digit uA's quiescent) technique to switch on a MOSFET when an input signal rises above ~100mV (too low for direct gate drive)?

You can buy ICs like the [MCP6548](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP6548) that functionally accomplish this, but I am looking to do it with discreets.

I am thinking there might be a way to bias a MOSFET gate so that the 100mV falls right in the transition region, and triggers positive feedback loop to throw it in to full active region, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: What is the signal rise time?

Comment: What DC voltage do you have available to drive the gate?

Comment: 1uA MCP6548 with  pullup? or pushpull?

Comment: What about a comparator?

Comment: The technique is called "amplifier".

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist yes, this the functionally I am looking for but I'd like to recreate it using discreets. So I guess my question could be re-asked "How do low voltage sub-uA comparators like the MCP6548 work on the inside?" Thanks!

Comment: @laptop2d Yes! Do you know how to build a comparator that draws single digits of uA's out of discreets?

Comment: @EE_socal 3VDC supply

Comment: @JohnBirckhead On the order of 10's of milliseconds.

Comment: How much do you know about analog FET design?

Comment: @AliChen Not if your thresholding and have it in an open loop mode

Comment: AC or DC? Do you mean AC by ~ or do you mean approximately by ~?

Comment: @winny `~` = approximately

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Not as much as I'd like to! Any recommendations to good references so I can learn more about how to do stuff like this?

Comment: Bummer. Bootstrapping from 100 mV won’t be easy.

Comment: Do you mean 100mV referenced to ground or two floating wires which have 100mV between them?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc8k51.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can drop the +9 volts to +6v or maybe +4 or +3v.

The slewing of Q11 collector, from fully one direction to the other, may set the propagation delay.

Headroom on Q2 and Q3 is marginal; you may need triple Darlingtons to create more headroom, to drive the NPN diode loads.

Comment: Will this work? I would have thought that 100mV on the Vin input would not be enough to push Q1 into the active region.

Comment: notice the far right transistor is biased to + 0.1 volt; there is lots of gain here; there is no hysteresis. View this circuit as an analog comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting solution I found that uses an optocoupler as a constant current source to boost the input signal up the gate threshold voltage...

[image]

https://www.electronicdesign.com/power/simple-circuit-overcomes-mosfet-gate-threshold-voltage-challenge

While this is clever, it is not low power since the optcoupler's LED is always on. It is also non-optimal since you must manually adjust the booster so it does not automatically adjust to changing temperature.

There has to be a lower power way to boost that input signal that uses feedback to automatically adjust to exactly the bottom of the MOSFET's linear region.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a way of doing what you think. You can indeed bias the input up, but the gm (change in drain current / change in gate voltage) is so low that switching does not happen, just a small change in current from on to a bit more on. Then with a fet, the voltage where this happens varies enormously from fet to fet.

With a bipolar it works a bit better, but still gm is very low, so multiple transistors are needed. As you try to make the threshold closer to 0, and further from 0.5V, it become more sensitive to supply voltage and temperature etc.

This circuit gives you your 100mV at 2.5uA, and is a hard switching schmitt trigger. In theory. Its more like a useful circuit for a 300-400mV level.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhk89r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

That said, this just runs on the 100mV...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo5cPy.png)</sup>

Comment: I tried simulating this and it [does not seem to work](https://imgur.com/a/FOm84mT).[I changed the input driver to a 1hz square wave and then added an LED on the output](https://imgur.com/a/3FEeJSg). Am I missing something? How did you expect the transformer to work? Thanks!

Comment: The transformer+fet is called a joule thief. It is a power convertor, normally used to run a LED from a super low voltage source. They can start at as low as 40mV or so, and steps up the voltage to several volts AC which C1D1,2 turn into gate drive. Probably simuates very poorly. Bipolar joule thief is also possible , when you apply a tiny bias to the base from your supply it can start at low voltages (without bias it needs 400mV to start). a BJT joule thief has a 1:1 transformer, so you probably need an extra winding.